# select's MODEL clause to add columns on the resultset, not just new rows?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

PIVOT can only pivot one value into its one column.
Also PIVOT is not helpful if for examle we want to pivot and (group by) intersecting ranges of values.

So we're planning to use MODEL clause to overcome this limits.

We have to pivot into columns:

- sum(), count() of data over separate quarters for last 2 years and
  present each quarter's result into its own set of column;
- sum(), count() of data over separate years for last 2 years and present each years's result into its own set of column;
- sum(), count() of data over separate months for last 3  months and present each month's result into its own set of column.

The list of quarters / years / months in the bucketing is fixed and can be hard-coded in the MODEL clause (i.e. it'll be always to look back 2 years).

I have a working prototype doing above using three separate pivots, but it is very inefficient because each pivot has to pass our huge dataset again.

We expect MODEL might require just one pass over the dataset.

Questions:

- Is it possible for MODEL clause to create new columns (ie. we group
  by month and product category in a subquery, but MODEL should add
  columns for the above quarter/year/month buckets)?
- Can't think of a best way to define DIMENSION BY and MEASURES so we could 
  create new columns.. any ideas are highly appreciated.

Edit: posted the same question at https://community.oracle.com/message/13951429

Answer (score 1):

You can PIVOT with multiple pivot columns and multiple result columns

```
with atc as
   (select owner, table_name, column_name, data_type, nullable
   from all_tab_columns
   where table_name = 'ALL_TAB_COLUMNS')
select * 
from atc
pivot 
      (max(column_name) as max_col_name, min(column_name) as min_col_name
      for (data_type, nullable) in
         (
            ('NUMBER','N') as dt_number_n, ('VARCHAR2','N') as dt_vc_n,
            ('NUMBER','Y') as dt_number_y, ('VARCHAR2','Y') as dt_vc_y
         )
   )
```

Comment: Thanks Gary. Unfortunatally that does not help. 1) Try for example PIVOT data_type is in ('NUMBER','VARCHAR2') into the same "result column" :-) That's what I meant by "PIVOT can only pivot one value into its one column". https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#CHDFAFIE : … *Each* aggregated *value* is transposed to the appropriate new column in the cross-tabulation … 
2) Also you can not PIVOT the same value more than once e.g. ('NUMBER','VARHCAR2') into one result column, and ('NUMBER','DATE') into another as 'NUMBER' is duplicated.